# Login issues wordpress page

Tags: login

When my users want to login on my wordpress site, sometimes the process keeps hanging (circle in dots keeps spinning). Sometimes they get a green screen (login ok) and the username isn't showing up. So they think they can't login and bounce. But in reality, they are logged in. Clicking on a onther page, and the username pops up. See: https://www.loom.com/share/4a482c8f645c43d3abb2c081cf052c24
I've done a reset of cache on the server and deactivated the cache plugin on wordpress dashboard. Also a restore of .htaccess file.
Please, help me out. Thanks in advance! Kind regards

Comment: If you can reproduce this you should look in your browsers debug tools for either a server error returned on the network tab or an error in the script console for the AJAX login step. You could look in the web server's error logs too for anything that happens at the same time. However I'd guess this is a bug in the client-side login script, whether you see a script error or not. If there are no errors you should report this to whoever wrote the AJAX login plugin you're using, or the theme authors if it's part of the theme.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I'll contact the theme author!